# scrolling list problem

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a list item which scrolls up and appends the first item on the list to the bottom every 5 seconds but my the problem is that, i would like the entire list to scroll for better syn. The demo of the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2DNV3/4/). If you watch closely, only the 2nd, 3rd and 4th item scroll up...What can i do to improve this please?

Comment: working fine in chrome & FF. in which browser are u having problems?

Answer (score 0):

What happens on the "the 2nd, 3rd and 4th item scroll up"?

Anyway, this is what I believe is a better version:

```
function test() {
var a= $("ul li:first-child");
    a.slideUp("slow", function(){
        a.appendTo("ul").slideDown();
    });
};
window.setInterval(test, 1000);
```

**EDIT:**

```
function test() {
var a= $("ul li:first-child");
    a.slideUp("slow", function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    var b = a.clone();
    b.appendTo("ul").hide().slideDown();
};
window.setInterval(test, 1000);
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2DNV3/20/**

**EDIT 2:**

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qsem9/**

```
var scroll = function(){
    var first  = $("#scroll > li:eq(0)");
    var last = first.clone().appendTo("#scroll");

    $("#scroll").animate({ "scrollTop": first.outerHeight()  }, 500, function(){
        first.remove();
    });

    window.setTimeout(scroll, 1000);
};

$("#scroll").css({ height: $("#scroll").outerHeight() });

scroll();
```

This way, you have seamless scrolling no matter what - because it is *actually* scrolling. ;)

Comment: The the 2nd, 3rd and 4th are fine but is it possible to make the first item slide up just the way the 2nd, 3rd and 4th are...?

Comment: brilliant...but as soon as i add a height of 30px to the css...it looks like the previous code?

Comment: sorry i meant if you add li { height: 30px; }, you would notice that the first item is not sliding up, instead it is replaced by the 2nd item..can't the entire list slide up in one syc?

Comment: Nice example, but is there a reason you can't use the ticker used there?

Comment: Not neccessarily, would just like to know how to extend my code to accomodate this..