# Jquery Sliding dynamic List

Tags: jquery, image, youtube-api, dynamically-generated, sliding

I am using the  Piece of code given here :

http://jsfiddle.net/qsem9/  from  [scrolling list problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488099/scrolling-list-problem)

in an image list slider, and it is working nicely , but when I try  to fill the list dynamically with youtube thumbnails
 (also using another code taken from http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/tqWxc/ 
also from,  [How to get a youtube playlist using javascript API and json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560311/how-to-get-a-youtube-playlist-using-javascript-api-and-json))

trying to merge the two codes together to show sliding images this will cause the jquery effect to change from scrollTop to jumping or something else but not scrolling at all.  I thought the problem in the initial size of the list  item that document ready grabbed initially So I manually added one list item  to preserve the size. this will slide nicely only the first two images but after that it will start the the jumper sliding. Here is the example

http://jsfiddle.net/pQR7g/

Answer (score 0):

Tried modifying your code and check it out

http://jsfiddle.net/pQR7g/3/

Comment: Nice trick, but you will end-up with very high negative number for top attribute which will take the element out the page, second it will break the infinite loop  of the  list

Comment: There should be a way to stop infinite loop. I hope you will find it.

Comment: The continuous loop is essential for the slider, Hope someone can find the mistake in this code